# PHP Compress large file make server can not respond

Tags: php

My site have much music and picture resource.

User can login my site and download those resource.
When user click 'download' button , PHP will compress those selected files, then users will download the compressed file(zip).

**The problem is:**

> When PHP compress files, Other users visit to my site would have been
>   waiting for a response until the compression is completed

**So:**

> how to make PHP compression , while users can also  visit my website
>   fast?

Comment: unless you're serving up raw .bmp or .wav files, there's almost NO point in re-compressing compressed formats. .jpg and .mp3-type files will generally be almost incompressible to begin with.

Comment: Why not compress all the files beforehand, then just give them the file when they want it.

Comment: `tar` would be less CPU expensive than `zip`.

Comment: Implement an asyncronous "compression" queue, like facebook and google have. Use cronjob or CLI scripts, after finishing, send the user an email with a download link. Worries about time will be gone =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First reply to Marc B and crafter. By compressing files to zip archive you can send *multiple files* at once. This options is often on file and image hostings. For example this is the way you can download all photos from Google+ album.

Now, about problem. First thing to do is to set compression level to zero since compression is not what you really want. Be setting compression to zero you'll send (here i simplify a little) concatenated files with ZIP header in the beginning. If you you use some sort of outpout buffering, you'd better disable it for this functionality.

Also if you use  Apache you may consider mugration to NGINX+PHP-FPM. It deals much better with such tasks.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I carefully read your reply, And i try to use **pclzip** and **ZipArchive**, But it seems those two zip tool can not set the compression level. Could you please recommend some zip tool that can set compression level. thanks

Comment: If you use pclzip, you must add each file with PCLZIP_OPT_NO_COMPRESSION flag as second parameter.

Comment: Did this flag meaning **Do Not Compress**?,Just merger those file to a single zip file?

Comment: I add the PCLZIP_OPT_NO_COMPRESSION flag to parameter, But the problem again

Comment: Right. It will stick multiple files to one. What exactly do you mean by "But the problem again" ?